# Data collection in concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a question regarding the context (or scope) of the multi-process when using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and I am wondering if some one can give me a hint here.

What I am doing is pretty simple: in `MyClass`, there is a public function `compute_process_manager` and I pass in a number, e.g. `num=10`; in this function, I traverse through [0, num), used `ProcessPoolExecutor` to create a pool of processes, and pass the traversed value to a private function `_compute_task`. Function `_compute_task` just adds the input value with 10, and return both the input value and input value + 10.

I coded to ways to collect the result. `self.result1` will have the value as I expected, but `self.result2` is empty~! For the formal one, I use a list to collect all the returns from the process pool, wait until all the process completed, and use the value in the list to update `self.result1`. For the latter one, I update `self.result2` in the process during the run time.

I found this quite interesting and I am wondering what makes such difference.

Thanks in advance~!

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, num_proc=10):
        self.num_proc = num_proc
        self.base = 10
        self.result1 = dict()
        self.result2 = dict()

    def compute_process_manager(self, num):
        # process manager
        list_result = list()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(self.num_proc) as executor:
            for val in range(num):
                list_result.append(executor.submit(self._compute_task, val))
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)

        for result in list_result:
            key, val = result.result()
            self.result1.update({key: val})

    def _compute_task(self, key):
        # task to compute
        val = self.base + key
        self.result2.update({key: val})
        time.sleep(1)  # sleep for one second
        return key, val


def main():
    my_class = MyClass(num_proc=10)
    my_class.compute_process_manager(10)

    print('Result 1')
    [print('key = {} and val = {}'.format(key, val)) for key, val in my_class.result1.items()]

    print('Result 2')
    [print('key = {} and val = {}'.format(key, val)) for key, val in my_class.result2.items()]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()

    print('running time = {} second'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

If I set up a breakpoint at the line `time.sleep(1)  # sleep for one second`, `self.result2` is indeed in the scope of function, and `self.result2` is updated. But for some reason, when I get to the main process, `self.result2` is empty.

I believe I must missed some important concept here. BTW, I also tried ThreadPoolExecutor, both `self.result1` and `self.result2` have the values as I expect.

[variables at the breakpoint at an arbitrary process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dhxM.png)